# WebExecute to click and select next page

Tags: webtools

I am trying to get option data from BarChart.com with the following code:-

```
session = StartWebSession["Chrome"];
WebExecute[session,OpenPage" ->"https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/options"];  
WebExecute[session, "ClickElement" -> {"CSSSelector", "select.ng-pristine"}]
```

And I have difficulty to change the expiry date. With the above code, I can click the expiry but not being able to move to next expiry. How can I do this properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I was wrong, the element can be selected using the `CSSSelector`

```
expiration = 
 WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> {"CSSSelector", "select.ng-pristine"}]
```

---

The element needs to be located first. I don't think it can be done using `{"CSSSelector", "select.ng-pristine"}`. One way using XPath (which you can get using Chrome developer tools).

```
expiration = WebExecute[session,
   "LocateElements" -> 
    "XPath" -> 
     "//*[@id=\"main-content-column\"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/select"] // First
```

Get list of possible values

```
WebExecute[session, "ElementText" -> expiration]
```

> 2020-01-17 2020-01-24 (w) 2020-01-31 (w) 2020-02-07 (w) 2020-02-14 (w)
>   2020-02-21 2020-02-28 (w) 2020-03-20 2020-04-17 2020-06-19 2020-07-17
>   2020-09-18 2021-01-15 2021-06-18 2021-09-17 2022-01-21 2022-06-17

Select a value

```
WebExecute[session, "TypeElement" -> {expiration, "2020-03-20"}]
```